# Symfony on sharing host, No input file specified.

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to upload my symfony2 project on godaddy, on a sharing host.

I have several problems like a message : `No input file specified` when i login, register or other action.

Do you know something about this error message ?

Comment: will this help you? - http://wilt.isaac.su/articles/symfony2-no-input-file-specified-

Comment: and this - http://support.statamic.com/kb/hosting-servers/running-on-godaddy

Comment: I don't know how this can be related to login or register actions, but low permissions of files also can make server to give this error..

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that's related with the PHP version is running on godaddy server. But it should be related also with another tools they use for compilation process.